# Як перекласти українською слово "entity" в значенні "об’єкт, але не зовсім" в контексті програмування?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

З англійського [Вікісловника](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entity) можна дізнатися, що англійське слово "entity" може бути перекладено українською двома способами: як "об’єкт" і як "сутність", залежно від відтінку значення. Чи можу я перекласти "entity" як "сутність" в контексті програмування?

В англійській термінології комп’ютерних наук спочатку слово "object" використовувалося так само, як і в інших сферах науки - для позначення якоїсь абстрактної речі, але в 90-х роках слово "object" було загарблене концепцією ["об’єктно-орієнтованного програмування"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1'%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) (ООП) для специфічного для ООП терміну, тож для позначення об’єктів поза концепцією ООП часто використовують слово "entity".

Українська Вікіпедія на [сторінці "сутність"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) розповідає лише про філософські значення цього слова, але програмістська "сутність" зустрічається, наприклад, в статті про [модель «сутність-зв'язок»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%C2%AB%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%E2%80%94_%D0%B7%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA%C2%BB). Наскільки цей переклад доречний?

Comment: Як запитникові [одиниця](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=entity&highlight=on)?

Comment: У статті про модель «сутність-зв'язок» розрізняють два поняття -  *сутність типу* і *екземпляр сутності*. От те, що там називається *екземпляром сутності* і є те, що в [ООП](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%27%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) називається об'єктом.

Comment: Я завжди перекладав «entity», як «сутність». (До речі, слово «об'єкт» не зовсім загарбане об'єктно-орієнтованим програмуванням, у Сі і, як наслідок, у Сі++ слово «об'єкт» є терміном із [зовсім іншим значенням](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).)

Comment: Підтримую коментар вище, для слова "entity" завжди використовую "сутність".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010р. (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=entity&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> entity = ['ɛntəti] ***1. суть 2. су́тність*** 3. одини́ця 4. ко́мплекс;
>   об’є́кт; катего́рія 4. ці́ле

[Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська 2010р. (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=entity&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> entity  ***1. суть, су́тність*** 2. одини́ця; (одне́) ціле, ці́лість; (цілий)
>   об’є́кт 3. (х.) індиві́д  ['εntəti, 'εnt̬ət̬i]

Отже, цілком нормативний переклад слова ***"entity" - "сутність"***. Сміливо можете його використовувати.